# Application wont start "Unfortunately the application has stopped"?

Tags: android, debugging

I am a beginner in android development and i tried to make a small app. it was working fine but, then i started fiddling with the AndroidManifest file, but anyway i had to restore it from the backup i already created.
But **now the app starts but just to show the first activity**, and then it says "UNFORTUNATELY, APP TITLE HAS STOPPED".
I have tried the following:
1. Trying to find error in AndroidMainfest.
2. Project->Clean
3. Searching stackoverflow 
But nothing seems to work

This is my console

```
[2013-06-28 12:18:07 - start] Uploading start.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-06-28 12:18:08 - start] Installing start.apk...
[2013-06-28 12:18:14 - start] Success!
[2013-06-28 12:18:14 - start] Failed to install start.apk on device 'emulator-5554': device not found
[2013-06-28 12:18:14 - start] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: device not found
[2013-06-28 12:18:14 - start] Launch canceled!
```

and my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.start"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".StartingPointActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.davinci.STARTINGPOINTACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.davinci.MENU" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

my logcat output

```
06-26 20:36:41.007: D/dalvikvm(2673): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
06-26 20:36:41.567: E/Trace(2673): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-26 20:36:42.377: D/dalvikvm(2673): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 58K, 7% free 2497K/2676K, paused 29ms, total 33ms
06-26 20:36:42.377: I/dalvikvm-heap(2673): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.563MB for 1058416-byte allocation
06-26 20:36:42.507: D/dalvikvm(2673): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 3528K/3712K, paused 123ms, total 123ms
06-26 20:36:42.797: D/dalvikvm(2673): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 5% free 3528K/3712K, paused 6ms+32ms, total 290ms
06-26 20:36:43.317: D/gralloc_goldfish(2673): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-26 20:36:45.407: D/dalvikvm(2673): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 13K, 4% free 3637K/3772K, paused 32ms, total 38ms
06-26 20:36:45.407: I/dalvikvm-heap(2673): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.274MB for 635812-byte allocation
06-26 20:36:45.487: D/dalvikvm(2673): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 4% free 4255K/4396K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 72ms
06-26 20:36:45.487: D/dalvikvm(2673): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 16ms
06-26 20:36:45.777: E/ArrayAdapter(2673): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
06-26 20:36:45.777: D/AndroidRuntime(2673): Shutting down VM
06-26 20:36:45.787: W/dalvikvm(2673): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:735)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1652)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TwoLineListItem cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
06-26 20:36:45.927: E/AndroidRuntime(2673):     ... 37 more
```

and splash.java

```
package com.example.start;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer song;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        song = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this,R.raw.chimesound);
        song.start();
        Thread timer = new Thread()
        {
            public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(2000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openStatingPointActivity = new Intent("com.davinci.MENU");
                startActivity(openStatingPointActivity);
            }
            }

        };
        timer.start();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        song.release();
        finish();
    }

}
```

menu.java

```
package com.example.start;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity{

    String Classes[]= {"Ëxample1","StartingPointActivity","example1","example2","example3"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, Classes));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String activityName = Classes[position];
        try
        {
        Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.start." + activityName);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this,ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



}
```

Please HELP !

Comment: Provide code of your Splash activity

Comment: Did you try restarting emulator?

Comment: You've provided the error log for the first error, but not for the second, which is described by " But now the app starts but just to show the first activity, and then it says "UNFORTUNATELY, APP TITLE HAS STOPPED"". Please do so.

Comment: are u change the min sdk version?
restart your emulator and eclipse

Comment: Please post the logcat output.

Comment: Also, please provide Menu activity code - it seems problem here.

Comment: i have also added the menu.java and created another emulator but now the app wont show in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

try installing your apk by command prompt. Open cmd and write

```
adb install start.apk
```

which is in your bin folder of your project.
Don't forget to go bin directory before this command.i.e.

```
cd C:/path/to/your/bin
```

Comment: it says "'adb' is not recognized as an internal or internal command"

Comment: you can set that see this  http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-set-up-android-adb-and-fastboot-on-windows-tutorial/  or http://techmell.net/android-tips/setu-adb-fastboot-android-sdk/